# UITableView with slide switch to data from other arrays and indicator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

How to implement UITableView with slide switch to data from other arrays and indicator?

[image]

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I don't have any problem with code. But I am beginner in Xcode and don't understand how to make few things.

Comment: Beginners can still do research.

Answer (score 0):

[UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) can help you to implement switching between table view controllers by sliding from left to right and vice versa.

[UIPageControll](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol) is to display a horizontal series of dots, each of which corresponds to a page.

Comment: But if I want to switch the a table (or tables) inside one page?

Comment: Implement your custom PageViewController based on [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview) that will switch views. But I can't image the task that can't be solved by UIPageViewController in this case.